# Error in MySQL synax inserting new data c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I think its one of those question where you need a second pair of eyes to have a look at.

I trying to add new record and just keep getting same error which is "Error in SQL syntax , I am using MySQL and here is the table

script for  MySQL

```
create table tbl_employee(
    employeeID smallint,
    employee_Fname varchar(30),
    employee_Sname varchar(30),
    employee_AddressL1 varchar(100),
    employee_AddressL2 varchar(100),
    employee_PostCode varchar(10),
    employee_tel_type enum('work', 'mobile', 'personal'),
    employee_Image varchar(250),
    employee_Job_Role     enum('admin','accounts','management','maintiantance','Sales'),     
    employee_Salary float,
    employee_imagePath varchar(250),
    employee_tel_no varchar(100),
    Primary key(employeeID)

);
```

and here is the C# code

```
        connected = DataConnection.getConn();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", connected); // 
        //This is my insert query in which i am taking input from the user through windows forms  
        //insert into tbl_employee value (2,'John','Rafiq','234 Zoo Rd','Alcala','2388','work' ,'admin',3500.89,'C:\blindXimages','111-111'  );
        string Query =  "Insert into tbl_employee (employeeID,employee_fname,employee_Sname,employee_AddressL1,employee_AddressL2,employee_PostCode, employee_tel_type,employee_Job_Role,employee_Salary,employee_ImagePath,employee_tel_no)" +
        "'value('" +   Convert.ToInt32(   this.txtEmployeeID.Text) + "'," + this.txtName.Text + "','" + this.txtSurname.Text + "','" + this.txtAddressL1.Text + "','" + this.txtAddressL2.Text + "','" + this.txtPostCode.Text + "','" + this.txtTelType.Text + "','" + this.txtJobRole.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal( this.txtSalary.Text) + "','" + this.txtFaceName.Text + "','" + this.txtTelephoneNo.Text + "')";

        //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.  
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, connected);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;

        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();     // Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.  
        MessageBox.Show("Save Data");
        while (MyReader2.Read())
        {
        }
        // connected.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }  

    btnAddNew.Enabled = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Data is save clearing all text boxes ");
    clearTextBox(); 
}
```

I have double and triple check my syntax just can't figure out were I am going wrong line by line. will very much appropriate this support.

Comment: All SQL injection problems aside, `value` should be `values` and not have a `'` before it.

Comment: Using a prepared statement would not have prevented this error, but it *would* have made it easier to find by reducing the tangle of escaped and unescaped quotes. Seriously, [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) are a good thing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "values" instead of "value" and add space before values.

Comment: Thank you so much Joachim , Darwin and myksoft , lot needs to be learn from a newbie like myself in regards to SQL injection its a topic in it self. Problem fix ,  by values and not value also ' cause this error.